# error MSB4018 - "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly when release build

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

After eight hours of trying to debug and solve this issue, I've come to the point of contacting you.
I searched the web to find a solution but none if it seems to work.

I'm building an Android app In Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 v. 15.8.7 using Xamarin.Forms 3.3.0.912540. With the Target Framework set to 8.1 (Oreo). When I set the Linking (in Android Options/Linker Properties) to SDK and User Assemblies it builds the project. However, when I try to set it to SDK Assemblies Only I get the following error:

```
Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Pages.BaseDataSource/<Initialize>d__22::MoveNext()' in assembly: 'Xamarin.Forms.Pages.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Log::Warning(System.String,System.String)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Projectname.Android
```

---

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018: The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018: Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Pages.BaseDataSource/<Initialize>d__22::MoveNext()' in assembly: 'Xamarin.Forms.Pages.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Log::Warning(System.String,System.String)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

I tried multiple ways to solve this issue like reinstalling ~~~~the Android SDK's, changing the Target Framework (Android 9.0, Android 8.0, Android 7.0), changing the Xamarin.Forms version to 2.5.1.527436. Removing all files in the bin and obj folder and trying to use Skip Linking Assemblies. I even tried to comment out some of my code and set off ProGuard, AOT Compilation and Bundle assemblies into native code. I also tried to remove references and put them back in.

It is driving me crazy. I don't want to build the application with the settings set to None (this works of course but the .apk will be too big).

Can somebody give me advice regarding this issue?

With kind regards,
Civart

Comment: 1. Ensure Xamarin.Forms is the same version in every project (.Net Standard, Android, iOS, etc) 2. Use the `SDK Assemblies only` option within the Linker. Going above that will almost guarantee something will be linked out without a custom linker configuration. 3. Clear your `bin/obj` folders in your projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I keep this post for all the people who might face the same issue.

I checked every version (Main project and Android project) like Jon Douglas said. Some didn't match so I recovered this. Although this didn't solve the issue it appeared that Xamarin.Forms.Pages wasn't installed in both projects so I installed them (with both having the same version). Now it works!